# how to increase the image size

Tags: graphics, floats

I have images of 586 X 444 but it looks so small. Can I increase the size to some extent through code? If any one can help, here is my code:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makecell}%
%table
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{times}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\removelatexerror}{\let\@latex@error\@gobble}
\makeatother

%\documentclass{IEEEtran}

%\usepackage[english]{babel}% redundant
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}
 \begin{figure*}
        \centering
        \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.48\linewidth} % <---
\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
\subfloat[ aaa ]{\includegraphics{Fig5.PNG}}\hfill
\label{Fig5}
\subfloat [bbb]{ \includegraphics{Fig6.PNG}}
 \caption{ccccc}
    \label{Fig6}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
\subfloat[aaa]{\includegraphics{Fig7.PNG}}\hfill
\label{Fig7}
\subfloat[bbbb]{\includegraphics{Fig8.PNG}}
 \caption{ccccccccccccccc}
\label{Fig8}
\end{minipage}
  \end{figure*}
  
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Minipage resets \textwidth, \columnwidth and \linewidth to the width of the minipage.

Comment: The text width is 470pt. In one row the images will not be wider than ~130pt each.

Comment: ok and what if one image is smaller than other can i scale all images to one size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to correct keys `Gin`. From

```
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.48\linewidth}
```

to

```
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
```

After that result will be:

[image]

Comment: i need to place 4 images in a row

Comment: If your all images had to be in one row, that they can not be bigger as you already have. Only if you can rotate page to landscape.,